# Java Textfield E-Mail must Contain Certain Characters

Tags: java, validation, email, textbox, textfield

I want to make a Java `textfield` for an email address, when I click submit it must contain an `@` and `.` in text for validation.

How do I do that?

[image: http://imgur.com/nYNBy1K]

My code:

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if(txtName.getText().trim().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must have name");
        jlblNameVer.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Phone Number Validation
     if(txtPhoneNum.getText().length() < 10)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must atleast 10 characters");
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (!(field.getText().contains("@") && field.getText().contains(".")))` should do the job for your question.

Comment: Yeah that worked great , Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not checking null's, You might run into null pointer exception.. please take a look at code.

```
if(txtName==null || txtName.getText()== null ||txtName.getText().trim().length()==0)
        {
            //must have name message
        }

        //Phone Number Validation
         if(txtPhoneNum==null || txtPhoneNum.getText()==null || txtPhoneNum.getText().length() < 10)
        {
            //Must atleast 10 characters
        }

         if(txtEmailAddr==null || txtEmailAddr.getText()== null ||
                 !(txtEmailAddr.getText().trim().contains("@") && txtEmailAddr.getText().trim().contains(".")))
        {
             //must have valid email address
         }
```